# Java getInputStream SocketTimeoutException instead of NoRouteToHostException

Tags: java, linux, sockets, https

I have an odd issue happening when trying to open multiple Input Streams (in separate threads) on Linux (RHEL).   The behaviour works as expected on windows.

I am kicking off 3 threads to open https connections to 3 different servers.  All three are invalid IP addresses (in this test case), so I expect an NoRouteToHostException for each of them. The first two return these as expected, and quite quickly. (see stack trace below)  However the third (and 4th when I tested it that way) do NOT give a no route exception.   They wait for ages, and then give a SocketTimeoutException (see other stack trace below).  This takes ages to come back, and does not accurately express the connection issue.

The offending line of code is:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

Has anyone seen something like this before?  Are there multi-threading issues with sockets on REHL or some limit somewhere to how many can connect at once...or...something?

Expected stack trace, as  received for first two:

```
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:559)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:158)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(HttpsClient.java:272)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:916)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
```

Unexpected stack trace, as received on 3rd:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:559)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:158)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(HttpsClient.java:272)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:916)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah.   see now I feel rather silly.  Prompted from the responses above I decided to just put the ip addresses into the browser and see what happened.   It turns out I was using the following IP addresses:
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3

Unfortunately, 3.3.3.3 IS a valid IP address, which is not responding.  So infact it was working fine all along.

I am now using proper non routable IP addresses 10.27.1.1 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Is the linux firewall blocking the connect?  If the output of `iptables -L` is populated that may contain your answer.  You can also test by using `telnet localhost <portnumber>` to check if the port is available.  If it is, telnet should say "connected", etc.

Answer (score 1):

If the invalid IP address is blackholed, then no response will come back, and you will get a timeout rather than a "no route to host".  The latter relies upon an ICMP error message being received back from the network.